# Qooxdoo - ignore a global variable from the config.json file

Tags: qooxdoo

Can you ignore a global variable such as OpenLayers from the config.json file?

I've been having to do this at the top of every class file:

```
/**
* @ignore(OpenLayers)
*/
```

I also tried this:

```
"lint" :
    {
      "lint-check" :
      {
        "allowed-globals" : 
        [               
          "OpenLayers"              
        ]
      }
    },
```

but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends which Generator job you are running. Your second approach, adding *OpenLayers* to the config's `lint/lint-check/allowed-globals` should well serve you when running `generate.py lint`.

But in order to make it also relevant for compile jobs (source*, build), you need to inject the `lint-check` key also to *their* configuration. Just fork this key out into a dedicated job definition, and then include it in the "worker" jobs, e.g. like this:

```
"my-lint-options" : {
  "lint-check" : {
    "allowed-globals" : [
      "OpenLayers"
    ]
  }
},

"lint" : {
  "extend" : ["my-lint-options"],
},

"source-script" : {
  "extend" : ["my-lint-options"],
},

"source-all-script" : {
  "extend" : ["my-lint-options"],
},

"build-script" : {
  "extend" : ["my-lint-options"],
}
```

Now all relevant jobs should honor the setting to ignore the *OpenLayers* global.

Comment: I did notice that other globals that I define in the "allowed-globals" array do not get processed. Any ideas?

Comment: Mh, cannot confirm. Which qooxdoo version are you using? Keep in mind that compile warnings are only processed when a file is actually parsed. The warnings are not shown when the parse result is taken from the cache. You can force re-parsing of the file by ``touch``ing it.

Comment: I'm running qx 2.1. I tried a distclean too, and it still is not recognizing the other allowed-globals.

Comment: It might be better to shift the discussion off of SO, to either the qooxdoo mailing list or the bug tracker. You'd probably have to post your entire config.json to dig into that.